# Why does a textbox lose its disabled attribute on postback but not its value attribute?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

This is my program

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
   function one() {
       $(document).ready(function () {
           $('#<%= textbox.ClientID %>').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
       });
   }
   function two() {
       $(document).ready(function () {
           $('#<%= textbox.ClientID %>').attr('value', 'hello stackoverflow.com!');
       });
   }
</script>

<input type="button" value="one" onclick="one();" />
<input type="button" value="two" onclick="two();" />
<asp:TextBox ID="textbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="postbackButton" runat="server" Text="post back" />
```

1. When I click on 'button one', the textbox switches to disabled. Then I click on 'postback button' and the textbox switches to enabled (It loses what I set!).
2. When I click on 'button two', the textbox changes its value. Then I click on 'postback button' and the textbox doesn't lose its value.

How could I do to keep the disabled state of the button?
If I could do this on client-side it would be better..

Thanks a lot, Luciano.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.Net keeps track of posted values for you via the ControlState. If you had set the DISABLED state in the code behind (via enabled=false) then it would have been retained via ViewState.  If you had set it in the ASPX page, it would just be the value.  Since you're doing it via JS, the server has no way to know that it's been set.

one way to handle this is that you could do such things as keep a list of disabled textboxes by name in a hidden field.  Then on the post back, you could parse out the value from the hidden field, and set the enabled state of the textbox appropriately in the code behind, allowing ViewState to take care of things.

Comment: +1 I didn't notice initially that he was disabling through JS.. which is plain wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The reason *is* `ViewState`. Every changed property value of ASP.NET server control during the page execution will be saved by the `ViewState`. Read [ViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx).

Comment: ViewState is for programmatic changes that the server effects against the controls. If the ENABLED attribute was being set to FALSE in code-behind, then ViewState would come into play. Values set against a control in the HTML side of things or on the CLIENT via scripting are not stored in ViewState.

Answer (score 0):

Simple reason is you must be doing this.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Enabled = true;
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Enabled = false;
}
```

Here you Enabled button in Load event and then disabled it when first button is clicked. Then you hit the second button which is to do the postback it will just go in Page_Load event and Enable the button.

If you simply remove TextBox1.Enabled = true; from Page_Load, PreInit, Init event you will not see this error.

Don't enable disable through JS.

Answer (score 0):

If `textbox` with `runat="server"` attribute and  if it is disable then you cannot change its value using `javascript` or `jquery`.It can only change at server side